# Simple example of colcon test

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just starting to use ROS2. I have built a talker and a listener.

I also have a much more complex project that I have to understand.

so far I have understood about colcon build, but I would really appreciate if someone can point me to a simple way to use colcon test.

What is the general procedure if say I write a talker and listener in C++ and want to do some testing? Do my test have to be written in C++? or python?

I believe the way to understand complex things is to start simple so I would appreciate some help here. Later perhaps I could ask more specific questions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350704/simple-example-of-colcon-test/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2020-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`colcon test` simply invokes the tests of the package. For CMake-based packages that is using CTest, for Python packages it is `pytest`. For tests involving more than one executable you probably want to look into `launch_testing` (https://github.com/ros2/launch/tree/master/launch_testing) and `launch_testing_ros` (https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/tree/master/launch_testing_ros).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0